# The norm of the difference of two normal states

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

Let $M$ be a type III$_1$ factor and $\rho$ be a normal state on $M$. If $p$ is a projection in $M$, can we find another  normal state $\rho'$ on $M$ such that $\rho'(p)=0$ and  $\|\rho-\rho'\|=k\rho(p)$ for some $k＞2$.

Comment: It is rather confusing to have this question be repeatedly editted, which has now invalidated the (previously correct) answer below.  I am also curious about the "type $III_1$ factor" hypothesis: can you comment as to why you wish to make this assumption?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\rho'$ is faithful, and $p$ is positive (as it's a projection), $\rho'(p)=0$ implies that $p=0$. Thus you can take $\rho=\rho'$

Comment: But the whole point of this answer is that it's _impossible_ to have $\rho'(p)=0$ and $\rho'$ be _faithful_, unless $p=0$...

Comment: @mathbeginner: As Matthew says, the answer to your edited question is therefor "No".